# $\lim_{n\to \infty} \min_{a,b \in \mathbb{C}}\bigg[\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\bigg|\sqrt{|x|^3}-a\sin(nx)-b\sin([n+1]x)\bigg|^2dx\bigg]$

Tags: fourier-analysis, approximation-theory

> Let us define $R_n$ by:$$\min_{a,b \in \mathbb{C}}\bigg[\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\bigg|\sqrt{|x|^3}-a\sin(nx)-b\sin([n+1]x)\bigg|^2dx\bigg]$$
>   Calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty}R_n$

My attempt:

Let us define: $g(x)=\sqrt{|x|^3}-\frac{\hat f(n)-\hat f(-n)}{2i}\sin(nx)-\frac{\hat f(n+1)-\hat f(-(n+1))}{2i}\sin([n+1]x)$

Where $\hat f(n)$ is the $n-$th Fourier coefficient.

$g(x) \perp \text{span}\{\sin(nx)\},$ so by Pythagoras:

$\begin{align}
\bigg\|\sqrt{|x|^3}-a\sin(nx)-b\sin([n+1]x)\bigg\|^2
&=\bigg\|g(x)\bigg\|^2+\bigg\|\bigg(\frac{\hat f(n)-\hat f(-n)}{2i}-a\bigg)\sin(nx)\bigg\|^2\\
&+\bigg\|\bigg(\frac{\hat f(n+1)-\hat f(-(n+1))}{2i}-b\bigg)\sin([n+1]x)\bigg\|^2\\
&=\bigg\|g(x)\bigg\|^2+\bigg\|\bigg(\frac{\hat f(n)-\hat f(-n)}{2i}-a\bigg)\bigg\|^2\\
&+\bigg\|\bigg(\frac{\hat f(n+1)-\hat f(-(n+1))}{2i}-b\bigg)\bigg\|^2\\
\end{align}$

Therefore the minimum is obtained when $a=\frac{\hat f(n)-\hat f(-n)}{2i}, b=\frac{\hat f(n+1)-\hat f(-(n+1))}{2i}$

By Riemann–Lebesgue lemma: $\hat f(n) \xrightarrow{n\to \infty}0$

Hence, $$\lim_{n\to \infty} R_n = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\bigg|\sqrt{|x|^3}\bigg|=\frac{\pi^3}{4}$$

Is that correct?

Any help appreciated.